# ORA 00933 - "SQL command not properly ended" - Update with order by query

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to update a table that returns

```sql
code_langue      libelle
AA               Afar
AE               Avestique
AF               Afrikaans
AFG              Afghan
AK               Akan
...
```

i want to order libelle asc.

My query is

```sql
UPDATE typ_langues
SET libelle = libelle
ORDER BY libelle ASC;
```

i want this

```sql
code_langue     libelle
OM              Afan , Oromo , Galla
AA              Afar
AFG             Afghan
AF              Afrikaans
AK              Akan
SQ              Albanais
DE              Allemand
```

but it return error ORA 00933

thanks a lot

Comment: SQL records have no order inside the DBMS: they're like points in a set. There's no point in attempting to give an order to them.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: `SET libelle = libelle` that does not do anything unless maybe you have a trigger or something. What is it you are trying to achieve? "i want to order libelle asc." - you should not worry about the sort order of the records in the table. You sort the records when they are *retrieved* from the table using an `ORDER BY` at the end of the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: ok thanks, i know the select command but i thought it was possible to sort directly in the array (it's quite short and fixed) to save me time on the query..
Thank you all...

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to apply an order to a table (stored in a tablespace).

Instead, you can order a result set returned when you query the rows of a table by applying an `ORDER BY` clause to the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   typ_langues
ORDER BY libelle ASC;
```